# How to figure out where the webflux spend the most of time during processing requests

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, web, request

I am trying webflux in my project which is just computing something without accessing other services. The computing work is not very heavy. It just uses the PMML evaluator to evaluate inputted arguments, which are about 200 ~ 400 of string fields.

Most (95%) of the requests return fastly , in 5 ~ 20ms. But under some condition, like QPS rises upto 300+, some requests return very slowly, even up to 200+ ms.

So, my question is what costs most? Are the requests queued somehow? What are they waiting for? Can I configure more threads for webflux to faster the work?

Thanks for your advice in advance.

My machine is 8core, 16G. And my service is assigned 8G/8G memory, load-balanced by F5.

To clarify the status, I use spring-boot 2.1.6, and just replace web with webflux as the following:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.rocway</groupId>
<artifactId>flux</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```